# Tabris - Identify Device ID

Tags: android, iphone, ipad, unique, identification

How can a RAP application retrieve unique identification number of a device ( Android, iPad, iPhone, Browser ) ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment.
We will put this on our list of feature requests.